Cannot read firebase dynamic link inside flutter app
I'm trying to read a dynamic link that I created on firebase inside my flutter application, I did all the configuration but I'm always getting null as a value.
Here is my firebase config:
Shortlink: https://******.page.link/test
Dynamic link: https://*******.tn/restaurant?id=64fdf73f3ac564fe091a22e6
my android manifest file code:
 <meta-data 
                android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" 
                android:value="true"/>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="******.page.link" />
            </intent-filter>

And here is how i'm trying to read the dynamic link:
Future<void> initDynamicLinks() async {
  print("Initial DynamicLinks");
  FirebaseDynamicLinks dynamicLinks = FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance;

  dynamicLinks.onLink.listen((dynamicLinkData) {
    final Uri uri = dynamicLinkData.link;
    final queryParams = uri.queryParameters;
    if (queryParams.isNotEmpty) {
      print("Incoming Link :" + uri.toString());
    } else {
      print("No Current Links");
    }
  });

  PendingDynamicLinkData? data = await dynamicLinks
      .getDynamicLink(Uri.parse("https://******.page.link/test"));
  final Uri uri = data!.link;
  if (uri != null) {
    print("Found The Searched Link: " + uri.toString());
  } else {
    print("Search Link Not Found");
  }
}

and this is my main function:
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  initDynamicLinks();
}

It doesn't return me anything and actually it does not listen to any links, note that i'm running it on an android physical device on debug mode. Thanks for your help!

how are you testing the link in debug app? have you followed this tutorial ? https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/flutter/receive

Actually moving the block of code to a separate page instead of doing it all inside main function gave a result, and while on debug mode!

Moving the whole block to a separate widget and calling the function inside initState solved the issue.
